# send operation to background in C

Tags: c, process, fork, semaphore

in C  I want to do 2 operation at the same time. Because of that I am using fork() function for it. For example I wanna both access menu ıtems and download something in the background. Now I use my display for show both(show download progress bar and menu items).

I have to access menu items while download in progress on background.

Download operation demands access to display as well as menu. Now Can I avoid download operation to access demand to display with semaphore and (if it is possible)how?

Comment: By using `fork` you're creating a new process, and the two processes doesn't have access to each other without [Inter-Process Communication (IPC for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). However, if you use [*threads*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) then both threads will share memory and you can easier share data between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on asynchronous (non-blocking) I/O. Don't use `fork()`, that gives you a new process which is not what you want or need for this.